What is the euler rotation order of a Fanuc robot?
I'm looking for the order of rotation of a CRX Fanuc robot. I have found on some forums that the order of rotation is XYZ but I have not been able to find this information in the fanuc documentation.
If someone can help me and tell me the name of the document with the information.
Thank you
